# Inno Setup mixing parameters with Literal Quotes with other parameters

Tags: inno-setup

I want to run regedit.exe with some parameters, but one of them needs to have quotes around it and the other doesn't. If I try to compile the following I get an error about mismatched or misplaced quotes:

```
Filename: "regedit.exe"; Parameters: "/s" """{localappdata}\LEAP\OutlookRedemption\Outlook2013_C2R.reg"""
```

So would the following work? (I don't want to test this on my machine because these reg entries are for versions of Windows and office that I don't have)

```
Filename: "regedit.exe"; Parameters: """/s {localappdata}\LEAP\OutlookRedemption\Outlook2013_C2R.reg"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should convert the file into `[Registry]` entries rather than loading a REG file via regedit.  This allows you to add support for uninstallation and filling in values based on user selection during the wizard, among other things.

But no, neither of the examples you have posted are correct.  If you really want to still do it that way (which is not the ideal option), this would be how you'd need to do it:

```
Filename: "regedit.exe"; Parameters: "/s ""{localappdata}\LEAP\OutlookRedemption\Outlook2013_C2R.reg"""
```